# Where should electronic devices be put when travel from India to US/UK via travel-ban countries?

Tags: airlines, regulations

The latest travel ban list from US/UK banned electronic devices larger than mobile on board. Some airlines like [Etihad](http://www.arabianaerospace.aero/etihad-airways-reassures-passengers-of-service-following-directive-on-us-bound-flights.html) require passengers to put all the devices into check-in baggage, rather than hand them over at the gate.

On the other hand, as far as I know, India strictly banned batteries inside check-in luggage. All those baggage will be off-loaded and passengers are required to remove the batteries.

So, when passenger travel from India to US via those countries in the list, where should those devices be put?

Answer (score 4):

The official [DHS](https://thepointsguy.com/2017/03/faq-electronics-ban/) statement says,

> “TSA recommends passengers transferring at one of the 10 affected
>   airports place any large personal electronic devices in their checked
>   bags upon check-in at their originating airport.”

So it will come down to the specific airline's policy. Some may allow you to check it before you board your flight to the US, other's may inspect you bag before you board your airplane in India and require you to check your electronic device.